# Android Intent filter to receive URL shared from Chrome

Tags: android, air, adobe

Updated...

I am trying to get my app to show up when you click 'share' in chrome but have not been successful.  Here is what I have and the app shows in the list of apps but then crashes when I select the app.  Since it is an Adobe Air app, I feel it has something to do with my activity name.  I have tried the app name, the package name "air.appname" but it keeps crashing.

```
<activity
    android:name="StartActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: How can both android schemes : http and https have the same android host : "*" ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to add the BROWSABLE tag.
Here is how mine looks:

```
 <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
       <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

hope this helps! Cheers!